# Java regular expression match two same number

Tags: java, regex

I want to use RE to match the file paths like below:

```
../90804/90804_0.jpg
../89246/89246_8.jpg
../89247/89247_14.jpg
```

Currently, I use the code as below to match:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)[/](\\d+?)[/](\\d+?)[_](\\d+?).jpg$");
Matcher m = r.matcher(file_path);
```

But I found it will be an unexpected match like for:

```
../90804/89246_0.jpg
```

Is impossible in RE to match two same number?

Comment: could you please explain little more. whats expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `\2` backreference instead of the second `\d+` here:

```
s.matches("(.*?)/(\\d+)/(\\2)_(\\d+)\\.jpg")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XjNKjS/1). Note that if you use `matches` method, you won't need `^` and `$` anchors.

**Details**

- `(.*?)`  - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `/` - a slash
- `(\\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `/` - a slash
- `(\\2)` - Group 3: the same value as in Group 2
- `_` - an underscore
- `(\\d+)` - Group 4: one or more digits
- `\\.jpg` - `.jpg`.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/sXVB30):

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(.*?)/(\\d+)/(\\2)_(\\d+)\\.jpg");
Matcher m = r.matcher(file_path);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Match found");
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
    System.out.println(m.group(4));
}
```

Output:

```
Match found
..
90804
90804
0
```

Comment: This regex works well. could you please tell me what different between \1 and \2? Thanks!

Comment: @YuchenHuang `\x` is notation for [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) where `x` is identifier of [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). `\1` will represent match from group 1, `\2` from group 2.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks! this explain really helps me understand \x.

Comment: @YuchenHuang You may find more [about backreferences in "Using Backreferences To Match The Same Text Again"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex with a capture group and back-reference of the same:

```
(\d+)/\1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ec63jR/1)

Equivalent Java regex string will be:

```
final String regex = "(\\d+)/\\1";
```

**Details:**

- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture it in group #1
- `/`: Math literal `/`
- `\1`: Using back-reference #1, match same number as in group #1

Answer (score 0):

this regEx `^(.*)\/(\d+?)\/(\d+?)_(\d+?)\.jpg$`

is matching stings like this:

```
../90804/90804_0.jpg
../89246/89246_8.jpg
../89247/89247_14.jpg
```

into 4 parts.

See example Result:

[image]

Comment: It will also match `12345/67890_0.jpg` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: if you dont want this you could use: ^(.+)\/(\d+?)\/(\d+?)_(\d+?)\.jpg$

Comment: I think you don't need to escape `/`

Comment: you are right. good hint. it simplifies it. i forget not to be inside windows style \\

Comment: "*if you dont want this you could use: ^(.+)\/(\d+?)\/(\d+?)_(\d+?)\.jpg$*" I think you missed the point of my previous comment. OP wants to match *duplicate* numbers, not *any* numbers. So something like `12/34_` shouldn't be matched, but `12/12_` should. To achieve it you can use [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)